# SpringBoot + Keycloak adapter setup failed

Tags: spring-boot, cors, keycloak

I try to secure a SpringBoot backend with Keycloak adapter.

- SprinBoot 2.1.9
- Keycloak 6.0.1

I'm just scratching my head over lot of bug and missing documentation. Currently, i try to make the keycloak adapter to correctly respond with Cors Header for a `401 WWW-authenticate` error.

I've investigated and found that securityContext is null in the class `org.keycloak.adapters.AuthenticatedActionsHandler`, resulting in header not set in response.

```
protected boolean corsRequest()  {
    if (!deployment.isCors()) return false;
    KeycloakSecurityContext securityContext = facade.getSecurityContext(); // This return null
    String origin = facade.getRequest().getHeader(CorsHeaders.ORIGIN);
    String exposeHeaders = deployment.getCorsExposedHeaders();

    if (deployment.getPolicyEnforcer() != null) {
        if (exposeHeaders != null) {
            exposeHeaders += ",";
        } else {
            exposeHeaders = "";
        }

        exposeHeaders += "WWW-Authenticate";
    }

    String requestOrigin = UriUtils.getOrigin(facade.getRequest().getURI());
    log.debugv("Origin: {0} uri: {1}", origin, facade.getRequest().getURI());
    if (securityContext != null && origin != null && !origin.equals(requestOrigin)) {
```

Following the code, i found that :

```
public class OIDCCatalinaHttpFacade extends CatalinaHttpFacade implements OIDCHttpFacade{

public OIDCCatalinaHttpFacade(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    super(response, request);
}

@Override
public KeycloakSecurityContext getSecurityContext() {
    return (KeycloakSecurityContext)request.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());
}

}
```

getSecurityContext return null.

So what i'm missing to make it work?

This is my springboot application.propertie

```
server.port = 8081
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
logging.level.org.keycloak=TRACE

keycloak.realm = spring
keycloak.bearer-only = true
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required = none
keycloak.resource = spring-boot-elide
keycloak.credentials.secret = *********************
keycloak.confidential-port = 0
keycloak.enabled = true
keycloak.cors = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use keycloak adaptor with keycloak spring starter and spring security. And use a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Config to handle CORS in the overriding configure method.

Refer this doc : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_boot_adapter